# Regex with React not giving the correct Answer with API call

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs

Basically when I make the API call it returns percent Change as  '(+0.04)' I have written regex to parse if it has either +, -, or none code below. The issue I am having is that it returns neutral rather than the correct response.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function Ticker(props) {
  const [state, setState] = useState({});
  const [status, setStatus] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    let currStock = props.stock;
    const options = { method: "GET", headers: { Accept: "application/json" } };
    fetch(
      "https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/company/profile/" + currStock,
      options
    )
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(y => {
        function positive(status) {
          //   The Goal being to set className to these so the css can be conditional.
          if (/\+/g.test(status) == true) {
            return "positive";
          } else if (/\-/g.test(status) == true) {
            return "negative";
          } else {
            return "neutral";
          }
        }

        setState(y.profile);
        setStatus(positive(y.changesPercentage));
      });
  }, []);

  console.log(state);
  console.log(status);
  return (
    <div className="stock">
      <section className="stockInfo">
        <h1>{state.companyName}</h1>
        <h3> {state.industry}</h3>
        <img src={state.image} />
        <h3>Financials</h3>
        <p className="positive">{state.changes}</p>
        <p>{state.changesPercentage}</p>
        <p>{state.price}</p>
        <a href={state.website}>Learn More</a>
      </section>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Ticker;
```

Answer (score 0):

You only want to check if < or > 0 ? If the return you get is neutral, it must be 0 ? 
In this case why don't take the string without parentheses and use Number() instead ?

```
const a = '+1.05'
const b = '-9.33'
Number(a); // 1.05
Number(b); // -9.33
```

Else, can you try these regex ?

```
.*[+]

.*[-]
```

Answer (score 0):

You passed `y.changesPercentage` to the `positive()` function, instead of `y.profile.changesPercentage`. Except for that, your code works fine.

However, part of the problem is that you put lots of unnecessary content in `useEffect()`, and you don't use destructuring enough.

This is how I would write this:

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const options = { method: "GET", headers: { Accept: "application/json" } };

const signs = {
  '+': 'positive',
  '-': 'negative',
  '0': 'neutral',
};

function positive(status) {
  const [sign] = status.match(/[+-]/) || ['0'];
  
  return signs[sign];
}

function Ticker({ stock }) {
  const [state, setState] = useState({});
  const [status, setStatus] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => { 
    fetch(
`https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/company/profile/${stock}`,
      options
    )
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(({ profile }) => {
        setState(profile);
        setStatus(positive(profile.changesPercentage));
      });
  }, []);
  
  console.log(status);
  
  return (
    <div className="stock">
      <section className="stockInfo">
        <h1>{state.companyName}</h1>
        <h3> {state.industry}</h3>
        <img src={state.image} />
        <h3>Financials</h3>
        <p className="positive">{state.changes}</p>
        <p>{state.changesPercentage}</p>
        <p>{state.price}</p>
        <a href={state.website}>Learn More</a>
      </section>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Ticker stock="msft" />,
  root
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I pretty new javascript, I have seen destructing but haven't used it. That is an elegant solution. Thank you I will look into that more

Comment: You're welcome :) This article - [14 Beneficial Tips to Write Cleaner Code in React Apps](https://dev.to/jsmanifest/14-beneficial-tips-to-write-cleaner-code-in-react-apps-1gcf) can give you some good markers.

Answer (score 0):

After testing the positive function it seems to return the correct output. Are you sure that API is fetching the correct info? You should test status to see if it fetching the data that you want it to.